# Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP

Tags: php, function, rounding

I want a php function which returns 55 when calling it with 52.

I've tried the `round()` function:

```
echo round(94, -1); // 90
```

It returns *90* but I want *95*.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to round up or down to the nearest result ending in a 0 or a 5, correct?

Comment: yes, i want to round up to a 5

Comment: @Pekka: no, 52 would give 50 then, 53 would give 55.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

This can be accomplished in a number of ways, depending on your preferred rounding convention:

### 1. Round to the *next* multiple of 5, exclude the current number

*Behaviour: 50 outputs 55, 52 outputs 55*

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
```

### 2. Round to the *nearest* multiple of 5, include the current number

*Behaviour: 50 outputs 50, 52 outputs 55, 50.25 outputs 50*

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (round($n)%$x === 0) ? round($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
```

### 3. Round up to an integer, then to the nearest multiple of 5

*Behaviour: 50 outputs 50, 52 outputs 55, 50.25 outputs 55*

```
function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) {
    return (ceil($n)%$x === 0) ? ceil($n) : round(($n+$x/2)/$x)*$x;
}
```

Comment: can i use this code

<?php
$x = 43;

$y = round($x,-1) + 5;
echo $y

?>

Comment: @ahmadbrkat Yes, if `48` should give `55`.

Comment: Beware: roundUpToAny(5) returns 10 with this function.

Comment: Thanks, Bing.  I wish I saw your comment before this bug burned me!

Comment: @Ryan - note that this is not a bug, it is a rounding convention

Comment: @Ryan - I've added an additional implementation which ignores the convention in cases the initial number is a multiple of 5, or the passed rounding amount

Comment: Hi, SW4! Your “function update” didn't quite work as advertised. :)

As you said, it will not round up to 10 if the number is already 5 but it will, for example, round up to 60 if the number is 55. I wrote a much more complicated function that addresses the problem but it looks like there must be a simpler way to achieve the same. 

I will share my solution here anyway and wait for a brighter mind to improve on my design. At list it works! :)

My version of your function is at the bottom.

Comment: Your function is almost perfect. It is now working fine on most situations but it doesn't deal well with float numbers. If, for example I wanted to round up a product price of 230.50, it would return the exact same number 230.5. It should return 235. My update of your function, ugly as it is, is still a better solution.

Comment: @DrupalFever...revised

Comment: I can see that you are making an effort to update your function in order to make it work correctly. Still, if you try to round up the number 230.25, it will return 230.25 instead of 235. In my opinion, "modulo operation" is not the right way to go in this situation.

Comment: @DrupalFever - updated, the assumption now being integers are the rounding amount passed. Feedback of course welcome

Comment: Thanks! I am glad to give you feedback. 

I am a little obsessed about this function because, a while ago, I used the earlier version of your function at work. Eventually, I had to spend several hours trying to troubleshoot a problem that arose from the flaws on your original function that I didn't immediately catch.

Comment: Don't get me wrong! I am not accusing you of anything. I assume full culpability for my troubles. I should have known better than to use something I found on the Internet without doing some preliminary tests.

Comment: @DrupalFever - not at all! Improving this code is for the wider benefit of anyone who comes across it in futures so all feedback welcome

Comment: Back to your current function update... As I said before, even after the update, your function is still not working right. Try yourself to round up the number “230.25”. It should round it up to 235, right? Well, it is not. It is rounding it down to 230.

Comment: @DrupalFever - you may want to read up on rounding conventions- of which this is one

Comment: @SW4, your third function here doesnt seem to work for values above 4, for instance, 4 returns 5, great.  But 4.1 returns 4, 4.2 returns 4, 4.3 returns 4, 4.4 returns 4 but 4.5 returns 5.  Why is that?

Comment: @Chud37 - when I copied over the code I didnt replace `round` with `ceil`, ammended

Comment: @SW4 I just figured that out:)  It was quite satisfying.  Thank you though!

Comment: This isn't a bug, rather something to keep in mind, when rounding negative numbers, they will round "down", ie. -52 will round to -50 not -55. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: You can simplify the "next multiple" with this: $x*(ceil($n/$x))

Comment: I changed the function roundUpToAny($n,$x=5) to roundUpToAny($n,$x=15) for my use case of steps of 15 increments, it worked very well for #2 solution, thanks.

Answer (score 142):

1. **Divide by 5**
2. `round()` (or `ceil()` *if you want to round up always*)
3. **Multiply by 5.**

The value 5 (the resolution / granularity) can be anything — replaced it in both step 1 and 3

So in summary:

```php
    $rounded_number = ceil( $initial_number / 5 ) * 5
```

Comment: So, `ceil( $the_number / 5 ) * 5` is the final answer. Or `round( $the_number / 5 ) * 5` if you want to round to the nearest 5.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer Based on the question and OP's comments it seems that the `ceil` version is the way to go.

Comment: This solution is better in every aspects than the accepted answer, it's easier to understand, faster and works with any number (including floats)

Answer (score 90):

Round down:

```
$x = floor($x/5) * 5;
```

Round up:

```
$x = ceil($x/5) * 5;
```

Round to closest (up or down):

```
$x = round($x/5) * 5;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, caters for both rounding up and down

Comment: This is what i want :)

Answer (score 4):

```
   echo $value - ($value % 5);
```

I know it's an old question, but IMHO using modulus operator is the best way, and far more elegant than the accepted answer.

Comment: But this rounds DOWN to the nearest 5.  To round UP you should +5 to the end of the equation if (and only if) $value % 5 != 0.

Comment: No offence but we are not here on a beauty contest. :) 

If your function doesn't do exactly what is demanded of it, elegant as it is, your function is not the right answer.

Comment: @DrupalFever it does exactly what OP was looking for save for the remarks Bing did a couple years ago which are easily implemented on top. Look up the modulus operator ;)

Comment: Mahn just didn't do all the thinking for you %value=(5-($value % 5))+$value;  ... and no offense, but elegant is better.

Comment: I agree, Praesagus! Elegant is better but only when it works. Try the number 200 or 105 to your solution and you will see. Of course, you can adapt your code to take into account this anomaly. However, the more you tweak your code, the less elegant it looks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this little function I wrote.

```
function ceilFive($number) {
    $div = floor($number / 5);
    $mod = $number % 5;

    If ($mod > 0) $add = 5;
    Else $add = 0;

    return $div * 5 + $add;
}

echo ceilFive(52);
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Gears](https://github.com/Cosmologist/Gears) library

```
MathType::roundStep(50, 5); // 50
MathType::roundStep(52, 5); // 50
MathType::roundStep(53, 5); // 55

MathType::floorStep(50, 5); // 50
MathType::floorStep(52, 5); // 50
MathType::floorStep(53, 5); // 50

MathType::ceilStep(50, 5); // 50
MathType::ceilStep(52, 5); // 55
MathType::ceilStep(53, 5); // 55
```

Source:

```
public static function roundStep($value, int $step = 1)
{
    return round($value / $step) * $step;
}

public static function floorStep($value, int $step = 1)
{
    return floor($value / $step) * $step;
}

public static function ceilStep($value, int $step = 1)
{
    return ceil($value / $step) * $step;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 2, round to -1, divide by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of [Musthafa's](/users/958502/musthafa) function. This one is more complex but it has **support for Float numbers** as well as Integers. The number to be rounded can also be in a string.

```
/**
 * @desc This function will round up a number to the nearest rounding number specified.
 * @param $n (Integer || Float) Required -> The original number. Ex. $n = 5.7;
 * @param $x (Integer) Optional -> The nearest number to round up to. The default value is 5. Ex. $x = 3;
 * @return (Integer) The original number rounded up to the nearest rounding number.
 */
function rounduptoany ($n, $x = 5) {

  //If the original number is an integer and is a multiple of 
  //the "nearest rounding number", return it without change.
  if ((intval($n) == $n) && (!is_float(intval($n) / $x))) {

    return intval($n);
  }
  //If the original number is a float or if this integer is 
  //not a multiple of the "nearest rounding number", do the 
  //rounding up.
  else {

    return round(($n + $x / 2) / $x) * $x;
  }
}
```

I tried the functions from [Knight](/users/501914/knight), [Musthafa](/users/958502/musthafa) and even the suggestion from [Praesagus](/users/58013/praesagus). They don't have support for Float numbers and the solutions from [Musthafa's](/users/958502/musthafa) & [Praesagus](/users/58013/praesagus) do not work correctly in some numbers. Try the following test numbers and do the comparison yourself:

```
$x= 5;

$n= 200;       // D = 200     K = 200     M = 200     P = 205
$n= 205;       // D = 205     K = 205     M = 205     P = 210
$n= 200.50;    // D = 205     K = 200     M = 200.5   P = 205.5
$n= '210.50';  // D = 215     K = 210     M = 210.5   P = 215.5
$n= 201;       // D = 205     K = 205     M = 200     P = 205
$n= 202;       // D = 205     K = 205     M = 200     P = 205
$n= 203;       // D = 205     K = 205     M = 205     P = 205

** D = DrupalFever K = Knight M = Musthafa P = Praesagus
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your function with the nearest rounding number of 9 but in case of 800 it returns only 801 . Numbers 5,6,7,8 are working. Maybe its a problem of round?

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
private function roundUpToAny(int $n, $x = 9)
{
    return (floor($n / 10) * 10) + $x;
}
```

Tests:

```
assert($this->roundUpToAny(0, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(1, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(2, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(3, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(4, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(5, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(6, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(7, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(8, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(9, 9) == 9);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(10, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(11, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(12, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(13, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(14, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(15, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(16, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(17, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(18, 9) == 19);
assert($this->roundUpToAny(19, 9) == 19);
```

Comment: Nice!. Do you have a "roundDownToAny" equivalent of this?

Comment: roundDownToAny ??

Answer (score 0):

```
function round_up($n, $x = 5) {
  $rem = $n % $x;
  if ($rem < 3)
     return $n - $rem;
  else
     return $n - $rem + $x;
}
```

Comment: Your function has a problem. It rounds 56 to 55. Since it is rounding UP, it should round it up to 60...

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this function in 20 min, based on many results I found here and there, I don't know why it works or how it works!! :D

I was mainly interested in converting currency numbers from this 151431.1 LBP to 150000.0 LBP. *(151431.1 LBP == ~100 USD)* which works perfectly so far, however I tried to make it somehow compatible with other currencies and numbers, but not sure if it works fine!!

```
/**
 * Example:
 * Input = 151431.1 >> return = 150000.0
 * Input = 17204.13 >> return = 17000.0
 * Input = 2358.533 >> return = 2350.0
 * Input = 129.2421 >> return = 125.0
 * Input = 12.16434 >> return = 10.0
 *
 * @param     $value
 * @param int $modBase
 *
 * @return  float
 */
private function currenciesBeautifier($value, int $modBase = 5)
{
    // round the value to the nearest
    $roundedValue = round($value);

    // count the number of digits before the dot
    $count = strlen((int)str_replace('.', '', $roundedValue));

    // remove 3 to get how many zeros to add the mod base
    $numberOfZeros = $count - 3;

    // add the zeros to the mod base
    $mod = str_pad($modBase, $numberOfZeros + 1, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    // do the magic
    return $roundedValue - ($roundedValue % $mod);
}
```

Feel free to modify it and fix it if there's anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can also consider this one liner. It's faster! Works for `$num >= 0` and `$factor > 0`.

```
$num = 52;
$factor = 55;
$roundedNum = $num + $factor - 1 - ($num + $factor - 1) % $factor;
```