# How to round off numbers in php?

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

I have to round off numbers but not in the traditional way. I want to round to 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 and so on. After rounding, the rounded number should fall to one of the numbers listed above.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried, what have you thought of?

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php should be what you need.

Comment: *Is it possible?*  - do you *really* think that something like this would be impossible to accomplish?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654002/1329367

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$rounded_value = round($original_value/5) * 5;
```

Or if always rounding down:

```
$rounded_value = floor($original_value/5) * 5;
```

Or if always rounding up:

```
$rounded_value = ceil($original_value/5) * 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php#32008

```
<?php 
// Rounding to the nearest fifth 
// or any other increment you wish... 

$percent = "48"; 
  $num = round($percent/5)*5; 
    echo $num; 
    // returns 50 

$percentt = "47"; 
  $numm = round($percentt/5)*5; 
    echo $numm; 
    // returns 45 
?>
```