# How do i get the round values of system time in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get round values of system time.

For example consider, now time is `6:02PM` and I want to get the output as `6:05PM`.

Is there any method???

Comment: You can get the time in milliseconds and to do any math calculation that you would like to

Comment: possibly this will give you some clues, you will have to break up the time into bits but that should be easy enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php

Comment: if need only hours just use `date("H");` and if you want ceil value of minutes then create logic that if `date("i");` is greater than 30 add 1 in hours..

Comment: @Uchiha If you test that with `6:02` instead of the required answer I am afraid it lacks something

Comment: Yes you're right my bad @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ceil function with php:

```
$next_five = ceil(time()/300)*300;
```

this will give you the next round five minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
 $now = time();     
 $next_five = ceil($now/300)*300;
```

This will round up even if one second above a five minute mark

User below function

```
function blockMinutesRound($hour, $minutes = '5', $format = "H:i") {
       $seconds = strtotime($hour);
       $rounded = round($seconds / ($minutes * 60)) * ($minutes * 60);
       return date($format, $rounded);
    }


    //call 
     blockMinutesRound('20:11');// return 20:10
```

Hope it helps ;)