# Rounding up the value with 0 and 5

Tags: php, rounding

- I want to round up the value with 0 or 5 based on the below conditions. For example:

  > ```
  > 160.1 to 162.5  ---> 160 (value expected)
  > 162.6 to 167.5  ---> 165 (value expected) 
  > 167.6 to 169.9  ---> 170 (value expected)
  > ```
- Below is my code which i tried with a scenario:

---

```
$main_value=3831.25;
if(is_int($main_value))
{
$main_value=number_format($main_value,1);
}

$arr = explode(".", $main_value);
$firstvalue=substr($arr['0'],-1);
$secoundvalue=substr($arr['1'],0,1);
//echo "<pr>";print_r($firstvalue.$secoundvalue);exit;
$default=$firstvalue.$secoundvalue;
//echo "<pr>";print_r($default);exit;
if($default>=1 && $default<=25){
  echo   $output=$main_value-($default/10);
}elseif ($default>25 && $default<=50) {
  $temp_val=50-$default;
  echo $output=$main_value+($temp_val/10);
}elseif($default>50  && $default<=75){
  $temp_val=$default-50;
  echo $output=$main_value-($temp_val/10);
}else{
  $temp_val=100-$default;
  echo $output=$main_value+($temp_val/10);
}
```

- But the output i coming as 3830.05. Is there any other way to get the
  expected output.

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php

Comment: no there 52 outputs 55 52 should be still 50, as per above value expected

Comment: ohk then answer of @jeoren would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the built-in [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function.

You can do that by dividing by 5, using `round()` and multiplying by 5 again. Note that you need to round the numbers in the middle down to meet your requirements:

```
$rounded = round($number / 5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) * 5;
```

[An example](https://eval.in/639268).

**Edit:** In javascript there is no `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` parameter and all values in the middle are rounded up. To get the same result, you can round the negative version of the number - which will be rounded up, towards 0 - and take the negative of that again:

```
var rounded = -Math.round(-number / 5) * 5;
```

Comment: @jeroen : can you please help in jquery also as well, means can you pls give the code in jquery also

Comment: @sivashanker You should try that yourself. What is the problem?

Comment: @jeroen : same code i tried changing in jquery also, since i seen a bug as  above in my code i posted in stackoverflow with php code . Please help me in jquery also. i am trying this since more than 8 hrs pls. If you help it will be a great help for me.

Comment: thank you very much @jeroen and you reduced my code also as well