# How do you get the file size on disk, and not the file size?

Tags: php

How do you get the size on disk of a specific file in PHP?

```
echo filesize("test.txt");
//Size         100 KB (102,836 bytes)
```

But on disk I have:

```
Size on Disk 104 KB (106,493 bytes)
```

How do you get the size on disk with PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want to take the result returned by `filesize()` and round up to the nearest multiple of 1024 (or whatever your drive's block size is). Here are several ways to round up the nearest X: [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will need to use PHP's built in [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) function. [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) will only return the actual size of your file which can at times be a lot less that the size on disk (for example, if your block size is 4096KB and your file is only 1KB, then your size on disk will be 4096KB for a 1KB file). What we are interested in specifically is the following array key returned by `stat()`:

> blocks - number of 512-byte blocks allocated **

As such, we only need to take the `blocks` key from your array and multiply this by 512. You can see the different outputs below (based on a 5968KB file on a 4096KB block size system):

```
echo filesize('test.txt');
echo stat('test.txt')['blocks'] * 512;
```

Which on my machine will return:

```
5968
8192
```

This is because I have a block size of 4096KB. My file is 5968KB so 2 4096KB blocks need to be allocated. This equates to 16 512K blocks so that is how we get the correct size on disk value.

If you are interested you can also find your systems block size using the below array key returned by `stat()`:

> blksize - blocksize of filesystem IO **

Please note however that if you are on a Windows server then this will not work as per the note in the docs below:

> ** Only valid on systems supporting the st_blksize type - other systems (e.g. Windows) return -1.

Answer (score -2):

according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

`int filesize ( string $filename )` should work

like:

```
$filename = "path/to/file";

$size = filesize($filename);
```

Comment: Isn't that the same function used in the question that OP said didn't return the correct result?