# Round number up to `.49` or `.99`

Tags: php

I'm trying to round number like this :

```
5,24785 => 5,49
5,74536 => 5,99
5,00000 => 5,00
```

I tried with https://php.net/round

But this return

```
5,24785 => 5,24
5,74536 => 5,74
5,00000 => 5,00
```

A php function can do it or I need to round up then remove 0.01 ?

Do you have some clues ?

Comment: Why does 5.00000 not round up to 5.49?

Comment: what's the logic behind this:- `5,24785 => 5,49`??????? And does the same logic will applied to all other cases too?

Comment: Have a look at adjusting the answer to this question [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php) by rounding to 0.5 and then minusing 0.01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need using custom round function for this. Because rounding to 0.49 is not a standard way.

```php
function rounder($num){
    $fln = $num-floor($num);
    if ($fln>0 and $fln<0.5) $fln=0.49;
    else $fln=0.99;
        
    return floor($num)+$fln;
}
echo rounder(5.24882);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing in php (i believe), you can do a manual check:

```
$number = "5.85458";
$decimal = $number - (int) $number;

if($decimal > 0 && $decimal < 0.5) $myNumber = (int) $number + 0.49; // x.49
if($decimal > 0.5) $myNumber = (int) $number + 0.99; // x.99
if($decimal == 0) $myNumber = (int) $number; // x.00

echo $myNumber;
```

Or just remove 0.01

Answer (score 1):

there is no function can do it, you need to round up then remove 0.01

Answer (score 1):

I modified **@GummaMocciaro** solution, which did the job for me. But I extended this code slightly, because the case `x.5` was not handled and null was returned.

I transformed it into `else-if` statements and assigned `$myNumber = $number` in the `else` block, which is the case for `x.0` and `x.5`, so a valid number is always returned.

```php
function roundPrice($number) {
    $decimal = $number - (int)$number;
    $myNumber = $number;

    // x.49
    if ($decimal > 0 && $decimal < 0.5) {
        $myNumber = (int)$number + 0.49;
    } 
    // x.99
    else if ($decimal > 0.5) {
        $myNumber = (int)$number + 0.99;
    }
    // else x.0 or x.5

    return $myNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 5.56;  
$num = round($num - (int) $num) ? round($num) - 0.01 : round($num) + .49;
// 5.99 output

$num = 5.38;  
$num = round($num - (int) $num) ? round($num) - 0.01 : round($num) + .49;
// 5.49 output
```