# Round to nearest 5 or 9 in PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, rounding

I need to round pricing of products to **nearest 5 or 9** with a PHP function.

**For example, it must always round up:**

```
$243 would round up to $245

$247 would round up to $249
```

Currently using the following code, but this only rounds to nearest 5:

```
function round_five($num) {
    return round($num*2,-1)/2;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: You've probably been down voted because you neglected to show some code you have tried.

Comment: go give it a whirl Dean, then come back and post your code when you get stuck.  SO is not a place where people write your code for you, but we are happy to help once you show some effort.

Comment: Hi welcom to Stack Overflow. Please read about [How to ask a Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to [provide a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Cheers

Comment: sorry, im new here, I have updated post

Comment: @Devon *up* to 245

Comment: Ah, I missed the always round up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit, non mathy but should work:

```
function round9($n) {
    $n = ceil($n);
    $r = substr($n,-1) > 5 ? 9 : 5;
    $n = substr($n,0,-1) . $r;
    return $n;
}
```

- first round up to nearest integer
- get last digit
- replace last digit with 9 if it's greater than 5.  otherwise replace with a 5.

**UPDATE:** I thought this was an interesting problem and now that we've got three correct answers which solve it from very different angles I thought I'd do a bit of performance analysis for my own curiosity.  neuro_sys's answer wins by far!  Here are the results in seconds to complete 10 million iterations:

```
time to build array: 1.7170281410217
round9: 10.753921985626
my_round: 1.6339750289917
rounder: 16.578145980835
```

*Test was run on an 8GB, 4 Core Linode VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 / PHP 7.0.14*

Comment: Perfect! forgot to mention above, there are decimal points, your code also works with decimal points. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem Dean - you stated "prices" and woocommerce -I figured that the numbers would have pennies involved

Answer (score 6):

By checking whether the remainder of division by 10 is less than 5, we round it to 5, otherwise if it is greater than 5, we round it to 9. If not, the remainder is 5, and we return the number itself.

```
function my_round($number) {
    $inumber = ceil($number);

    $mod_10 = $inumber % 10;
    $mod_5 = $inumber % 5;

    if ($mod_10 < 5) {
        return $inumber + 5 - $mod_5;
    }

    if ($mod_10 > 5) {
        return $inumber + 10 - $mod_10 - 1;
    }

    return $inumber;
}

echo my_round(243) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(247) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(5) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(9) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(10) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(0) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(5.1) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(8.9) . PHP_EOL;
echo my_round(9.1) . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
245
249
5
9
15
5
9
9
15
```

Requirements are a little vague, so it may still be tweaked to handle various other corner cases.

Comment: @Dean You're welcome, I just edited an off-by-one error, though, so make sure you got the correct one.

Comment: Can you explain your answer.

Comment: For an input of 5, this function returns 10.

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for catching that, I fixed it.

Comment: @Martin I have added explanation.

Comment: 5.1 gets me 5.1.  does not round to nearest 5 or 9.

Comment: @billynoah Thanks, I fixed it to handle float numbers.

Comment: closer but still doesn't work.  according to his outline, 5.1 should become 9.  in your function it becomes 5.

Comment: there you go.  reversing downvote to an upvote :-)  cheers, you solved it using math, which somehow feels better than my mostly string based solution.  still it's nice to have an example of a different way - this question seems easier than it is.

Comment: @billynoah Cheers!

Comment: @neuro_sys - see my updated answer above for some performance analysis if you're curious.

Comment: @billynoah Haha, excellent! I also like to benchmark things often.

Answer (score 1):

Related questions you should have read:

- [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

## This is the solution:

Because your issue is not using core mathemtics (5 and 9 are arbitary) or  large indicies (largest count is 5 digits, 0,1,2,3,4) , simply count the numbers up:

```
<?php
function rounder($n) {
    $x=[5,9];
    $zz = ceil($n);
     $b = substr((string)$zz, -1); 
    while( !in_array($b,$x) ){
       
        $zz++;     
        $b = substr((string)$zz, -1);
    }
    
    return $zz;
}

$array[] = 243;
$array[] = 247;
$array[] = 249;
$array[] = 240;
$array[] = 250;

foreach($array as $row){

     print rounder($row)."<Br>";

}
unset($row);
```

========================

Output:

> 245
> 249
> 249
> 245
> 255

This can probably be shortened down to a few lines of code..... but whatever

Comment: The question doesn't involve any cents

Comment: @billynoah cents are ignored.

Comment: 235.50 gets  me 235.  still wrong as it's not rounding up.  his question specifically states he wants to round *prices* and a price can be something other than a whole number.

Comment: @billynoah none of the examples contain cents; prices are not always cents. That's a detail you've applied; not a detail required by the OP. Anyhow. Fixed with a `ceil()` .

Comment: i don't think it was much of a stretch to assume that *some* prices may contain cents and when you are talking about pricing your are almost always talking about floats and decimals. anyway, i've reversed my downvote.  this is another good answer using yet a different technique.  cheers

Comment: see my updated answer above for some performance analysis if you're curious.

Comment: @billynoah thanks. I had originally marked yours + 10 because it works and is much smaller codebase than mine. tbh the whole concept of rounding prices to a 5 or a 9 seems non-standard so I can see an expectation that cents would be expected, but it wasn't in the OP originally....