# Rounding a price to closest multiple of 5

Tags: php

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to round the price to be always rounded up to nearest multiple of `5`?

```
 $fee = 364.99;
 $discount = 25;
 $price = round($fee - ($fee * ($discount / 100)))*5;
 echo $price;
```

I am hoping to get `275.00` the output is `1370`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

Comment: It is because you multiply by 5 at the end. `5 * 274 = 1370`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to divide by 5.

Correct calculation is

`$price = round(($fee - ($fee * ($discount / 100))) / 5) * 5;`

**In general**

```
$round = 5;
$calc = round($num / $round) * $round;
```