# How can I round up from number 621 to 700 in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$num=621;
echo round(round(621,-2));
```

Comment: Daniel if I am not wrong rouding is to the next number over .5 to the complete full number. If you round 621 it should be 600 not 700, by saying this you will have to code your own function to get your desired result.

Comment: This site might help http://eligeske.com/php/php-round-up-to-nearest-hundred-function/

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive? Is it rounding up to nearest 100?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round up to nearest multiple of five in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133859/round-up-to-nearest-multiple-of-five-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to round off a number to the nearest 100.
Simply do this by using the ceil function.

```
ceil(621 / 100) * 100;
```

You can use ceil function to round any number to its nearest number.

```
$number = ceil($inputNumber / $nearestNumber) * $nearestNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (returns the closest `$mul`tiple not less than the given `$num`ber):

```
function round_up($num, $mul) {
    return ceil($num / $mul) * $mul;
}
```

Called like this:

```
echo round_up(621, 100);
> 700
```

Works for "weird" quantities, too:

```
echo round_up(124.53, 0.25);
> 124.75

echo round_up(pi(), 1/7);
> 3.1428571428571
```

If you want to specify decimal places instead of multiples, you could use the power operator `**` to convert decimal places to multiples.

You could do `round_down` in a similar way using `floor`.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, subtract the reminder and add 100:

```php
function ceil100($value) {
    return $value - $value % 100 + 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is `$numero = $numero + 100 - $numero % 100;`

```
php > $numero = 621;
php > $numero = $numero + 100 - $numero % 100;
php > echo $numero;
700
```